# Is this integral expressible in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

While carrying out a calculation, I encountered this integral:
$$\int_0^1 d u~u^{-1-2 x} (1-u)^{-x}  \Big({}_2F_1\left(1, 1, 1-x; u\right)\Big)^2\,.$$
I read in Exton's book that it is expressible in terms of generalized Kampe de Feriet functions with both arguments unity but such an expression is not of much use to me. I don't think it's guaranteed that the integral can be evaluated in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions of unit argument (or related single sums) but I would be very happy if somebody could answer this in the affirmative.